# Retrieving query from 2 tables using eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I have 2 tables (projects and clients). A client can have many projects. A project belongs to one client.

Tables schema:
Client:

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('contact_person');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Projects:

```
  Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->date('due');
            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Here is the models:
Client Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
  public function projects()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
  }
}
```

Project Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    public function tasks()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Task');

    }

    public function client()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
}
```

Here are the controllers.
ClientsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ClientsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $clients = Client::has('projects')->get();
      return $this->hasMany('projects');
    }
}
```

ProjectsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use App\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $projects = Project::find(1)->projects;
      return $projects->all();
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      return $request->all();
    }
}
```

Project.vue

```
  <ul>
    <li v-for="project in projects">
      {{ project.name }} 
      // client's name here
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I want to return a query that will display all clients' name and their project name accordingly. All i can get for now is the project name only. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just after i post my question i found the solution. here it goes.

ProjectsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use App\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $projects = Project::with('client')->get();
      return $projects->all();
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      return $request->all();
    }
}
```

and the Project.vue

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="project in projects">
      {{ project.name }} || {{project.client.contact_person }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```